# How to get distinct values from PyMongo

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

In MongoDB I have a dataset of store data. 
Using PyMongo I am finding all of the distinct/unique values in a collection

```
for testy in collection.distinct('stores'):
print(testy)
```

I can also find a subset of badly spelt stores I'm interested in

```
for testy in collection.find({'stores': {'$in': ['Aldi','ALDI','aldi']}}):
```

What I want to do is find the unique in this subset

According to the MongoDB docs

```
db.runCommand ( { distinct: "inventory", key: "item.sku", query: { dept: "A"} } )
```

Tried lots of combinations adding the query doing the `$in` but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you are looking for is [**`distinct`**](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.distinct)

```
for testy in collection.find().distinct('stores'):
    print(testy)
```

or

```
for testy in collection.distinct('stores', {'dept': 'A'}):
    print(testy)
```